# The difference between InputStream and InputStreamReader when reading multi-byte characters

Tags: java, character-encoding, io

The difference between `InputStream` and `InputStreamReader` is that `InputStream` reads as `byte`, while `InputStreamReader` reads as `char`. For example, if the text in a file is `abc`,then both of them work fine. But if the text is `a你们`, which is composed of an `a` and two Chinese characters, then the `InputStream` does not work.

So we should use `InputStreamReader`, but my question is:

**How does `InputStreamReader` recognize characters?**

`a` is one byte, but a Chinese character is two bytes. Does it read `a` as one byte and recognize the other of characters as two bytes, or for every character in this text, does the `InputStreamReader` read it as two bytes?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

An `InputStream` reads raw octet (8 bit) data. In Java, the `byte` type is equivalent to the `char` type in C. In C, this type can be used to represent character data or binary data. In Java, the `char` type shares greater similarities with the C `wchar_t` type.

An `InputStreamReader` then will transform data from some encoding into UTF-16. If "a你们" is encoded as UTF-8 on disk, it will be the byte sequence `61 E4 BD A0 E4 BB AC`. When you pass the `InputStream` to `InputStreamReader` with the UTF-8 encoding, it will be read as the char sequence `0061 4F60 4EEC`.

**The character encoding API in Java contains the algorithms to perform this transformation. You can find a list of encodings supported by the Oracle JRE [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html). The [ICU project](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion) is a good place to start if you want to understand the internals of how this works in practice.**

As Alexander Pogrebnyak [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764065/inputstream-and-reader-in-java-io/5764111#5764111), you should almost always provide the encoding explicitly. `byte`-to-`char` methods that do not specify an encoding rely on the [JRE default](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset%28%29), which is dependent on operating systems and user settings.

Answer (score 10):

You have to give reader a hint, by providing a character set that your binary file is written in. E.g

```
Reader reader =
   new InputStreamReader(
       new FileInputStream( "/path/to/file" ),
       "UTF-8" // most likely that the encoding of the file
   )
```

Without a hint it will use your platform default encoding, which in many cases is not what you want.

This link has a nice explanation of encodings: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html