# Difference between BufferedReader and BufferedInputStream

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

What are the differences between `BufferedReader` , `BufferedInputStream` and `Scanner` in java? `BufferedReader` reads the text and `BufferedInputStream` reads `byte`. Is there any difference other than this?

Comment: Please, check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [inputstream and reader in Java IO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764065/inputstream-and-reader-in-java-io)

Comment: Scanner is almost the same as any reader, but it has a lot of methods for parsing input and it's not thread safe

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I guess, the difference is the same as between reader and inputstream: one is character-based, another is byte-based. For example, reader normally supports encoding...

**Edit:** Check this question: [The difference between InputStream and InputStreamReader when reading multi-byte characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764065/inputstream-and-reader-in-java-io)

Answer (score 11):

`BufferedInputStream` reads the data in the buffer as bytes by using `InputStream`. `BufferedReader` reads the text but not as bytes and `BufferedReader` is efficient reading of characters,arrays and lines.