# Decode error in BufferedReader

Tags: java, decode

I received some data from server and read them from java code :

```
is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));

int length;
char[] buffer = new char[4096];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while ((length = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
   sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, length));//buffer is already incorrect
}

byte[] byteDatas = sb.toString().getBytes();
```

And I print byteDatas as Hex string:

[image]

Comparing to the wireshark's result:

[image]

Some bytes are decoded as **bf bd ef** , I know it's \ufffd(65533) stand for invalid data.

So I think there must have decode error in my code , after debug, I found that **If I use connection.getInputStream() to read data directly , there is no invalid data**.

So ,the problem must happens in `BufferedReader` or `InputStreamReader`, But I have already add "UTF-8" and the data in wireshark seems not very wired. Does UTF-8 is not correctly? Server do not reply the charset.

Please help how to let `BufferedReader` read the correct data.

**UPDATE**

My default charset is "UTF-8" and have debug to prove it . After `read` return , I have already got the wrong data , so it's not String's fault.

Comment: You need to specify the charset when you read text input...that is the problem one way or the other.

Comment: I'm thinking that you're *not* reading character streams but byte content hence the issue with the data.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi they are byte content, I think this way can also read byte content.

Comment: @zzy not true. Read this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5764065/the-difference-between-inputstream-and-inputstreamreader-when-reading-multi-byte#answer-5764357) to best understand what I mean. Rather read the `byte` directly and hex encode it instead of using character arrays.

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I got it , now i don't know whether the server will reply `character` or not (`byte`), should I always read bytes not char to let data read correctly and let upper to decide whether to convert to `character` ?

Comment: Check the `Content-Type` header. This will tell you if the content is character stream or byte stream and what `charset` the data is encoded in.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.getBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--) will use the platform's default encoding (not necessarily UTF-8) to convert the characters of the `String` to bytes.

Quoting from the javadoc of `String.getBytes()`:

> Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes **using the platform's default charset**...

You can't compare the UTF-8 encoded input data to the result which might not be the result of UTF-8 encoded. Instead explicitly specify the encoding like this:

```
byte[] byteDatas = sb.toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

**Note:**

If your input data is NOT UTF-8 encoded text and if you attempt to decode it as UTF-8, the decoder may replace invalid byte sequences. This will cause that the bytes you get by encoding the `String` will not be the same as the input raw bytes.

Comment: The buffer is already wrong when I got it from `read`. It's not String's mistake.

Comment: Then it may be very well that your input is NOT UTF-8 encoded text and if you attempt to decode it as UTF-8, the decoder may replace invalid byte sequences.